# Trouble downloading NLTK on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, nltk

After `!pip install nltk`

```
Requirement already satisfied: nltk in c:\users\pravi\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (3.5)
Collecting tqdm
  Using cached tqdm-4.56.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (72 kB)
Collecting click
  Using cached click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib in c:\users\pravi\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages (from nltk) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: regex in c:\users\pravi\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from nltk) (2020.11.13)
Installing collected packages: tqdm, click
Successfully installed click-7.1.2 tqdm-4.56.0
```

`import nltk` gives me the message `name 'nltk' is not defined`

I want to know if this is a path issue or where I need to be looking to resolve this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the installation does not show any errors, here are a few things you could consider -

1. Are you installing the pip package in the correct environment? Usually, you should see the nltk package listed in the packages.
2. Are you using python3? Perhaps do the install with pip3 instead?
3. Reload the kernal for changes to take effect if needed.